# Python3 Pickle hitting recursion limit

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I have the following block of code that when executed on my Ubuntu computer using Python3 hits the recursion error for pickling. I don't understand why since the object to be pickled is not particularly complex and doesn't involve any custom objects. In fact, it is only a list of some 500 elements (approximately); each element of the list is just a string. It seems to me that I should be able to serialize this object without issue. Why am I hitting a recursion limit error? I know I could up the recursion limit with `import sys` and `sys.setrecursionlimit()` but I am frankly surprised I have to do that for such a trivial object.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pickle


def get_standard_and_poors_500_constituents():
    # URL request, URL opener, read content.
    req = request.Request(
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
    )
    opener = request.urlopen(req)
    # Convert bytes to UTF-8.
    content = opener.read().decode()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    # HTML table we actually need is the first.
    tables = soup.find_all("table")     
    external_class = tables[0].findAll("a", {"class":"external text"})
    c = [ext.string for ext in external_class if not "reports" in ext]

    return c


sp500_constituents = get_standard_and_poors_500_constituents()
spdr_etf = "SPY"
sp500_index = "^GSPC"


def main():
    import datetime as dt
    today = dt.datetime.today().date()
    fname = "sp500_constituents_" + str(today) + ".pkl"

    with open(fname, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(sp500_constituents, f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```